# Is libc.so.2 required to be located in /usr/lib?

Tags: linux, archlinux, libc, chroot

I have a directory with the following contents:

```
bin/busybox
lib/ld-linux.so.2
lib/libc.so.6
```

and when I invoke:

```
chroot . bin/busybox sh
```

it fails with the following:

```
/bin/busybox: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I move lib/libc.so.6 to usr/lib, it works fine.

Why is libc required to be in /usr/lib? When I invoke:

```
objcdump -p bin/busybox | grep NEEDED
```

I get:

```
NEEDED        libc.so.6
```

So I thought, as only the soname of the library is used without slashes etc. the loaded will be able to find it in the standard folders, which is /lib and /usr/lib. Apparently, this is not the case.

To make matters even more confusing, ld-linux.so.2 seems to have to be in /lib because when it is moved to /usr/lib, chroot fails with:

```
chroot: failed to run command '/bin/busybox': No such file or directory
```

which I learned is actually an error that the loader cannot be found, not the busybox binary.

Is the issue with libc.so.2 distro specific? If this is important, I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: set LD_RUN_PATH when compiling, or set the library search paths by exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running

Comment: Or do ln-s /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Comment: Thank you. These are ways to work around the issues (apart from keeping the files in the directories so that it all workd), but don't explain the original behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of the loader (typically something like `/lib/ld-linux.so`) is hard-coded in the binary. There's no search process for this component — if it cannot be found, the binary won't run at all.

(The exact path depends on what libc and architecture you're using. It's at `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` for glibc on x86_64, for instance.)

The locations that will be searched for dynamic libraries are configurable in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. If you don't have that file in the chroot, though, some of the standard paths may not be configured!

Comment: Is the hardcoded loader stored in the .interp header section? I though the .interp secion actually had the loader code.
Yes, I don't have ld.so.conf. I thought /lib and /usr/lib are the default defaults ;d i.e. in use even when nothing else is defined.

Comment: The path to the loader is stored in the `.interp` section, not the code of the loader. (On my system, the loader is about 150K on disk, which would be rather large to include in every binary!)

Comment: I was confused by the wording of the man 8 ld.so: (...) the dynamic linker which is stored in the .interp section(...)
I read the linker may be replaced by arbitrary code, which is why calling ldd on untrasted binaries may be dangerous. Does such replacement just replace the location of the loader? And does it accept relative paths?